# Erlang supervisor restart interval

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I have a supervisor with `one_for_one` restart strategy.
Is it possible to set some time interval between child process restarting?

For example, the remote db crushed and I want to wait 10 seconds between restore connection attempts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you could let the supervisor to immediately restart its children and implement what is called *lazy initialization*:

1. The supervisor (re)starts (immediately) the child (say, a gen_server)
2. The gen_server returns a 0 timeout in its init function
3. In the handle_info you do an active wait (your 10 seconds) to ensure the DB is properly initialized

This way, you ensure that all requests to the gen_server are processed after the DB is properly initialized.

Comment: Thank you, but I hav't problem with gen_server init, I want a time interval (sleep) between restart attempt.

Comment: I think what @Robert Aloi suggests will work. The gen_server's init would not try to reconnect, instead it returns the 0 timeout which will satisfy the supervisor that the child has started. Then, in the handle_info function you do the "real" initialization... After sleeping for 10 seconds

Comment: Or even better after ensuring that the DB is alive. Waiting a fixed amount of time is the root of all evils.

Comment: The trouble is that you **CANNOT** specify a time interval between retart attempts. There is no way to do it in the supervisor. @RobertoAloi is giving you a work around where the supervisor immediately restarts the server, as is its way, and you wait inside the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with standard `supervisor` behaviour, you need to implement your own `sup` as a `gen_server` which **trap exits** from others than its `parent` and restarts manually their childs, but which also check each time before restarting a child that the 10 seconds are expired by setting a `timeout`